# Erro ao editar cadastro de usuário com nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Estou com um problema em uma aplicação que fiz aqui no serviço. Uso o nested_form juntamente com o Devise para um cadastro de estudante, ou seja, quando cadastro um estudante, eu já adiciono um usuário para ele no sistema, que pode ter acesso à notas entre outras coisas. Porém, quando edito o cadastro, ele me pede para adicionar novamente a senha.Tentei criar os controller customizados, porém não obtive sucesso. Por isso, mando os links de alguns arquivos para que, uma alma caridosa possa me ajudar .

User Model
https://gist.github.com/luizpicolo/e5d3dbb533c0be1518b0

Student model
https://gist.github.com/luizpicolo/96d9f58c3ac2824ce3ef

Student Controller
https://gist.github.com/luizpicolo/30d0e9578848b2c12315

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851/101

Answer (score 0):

pelo que eu me lembre, o Devise pede para confirmar a senha sempre que o usuário for alterado.

A wiki do devise tem uma seção falando sobre isso. (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Mas como você está lidando com um nested resource, minha sugestão seria um hack dentro do modelo user, no qual você sobre-escreveria o update do User para chamar o método update_without_password. Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update(params, *options)
    update_without_password(params, *options)
  end
end
```

Mas vale lembrar que não tenho certeza que funcione, e lembre-se de que isso vai SOBRE-ESCREVER o método update em todos os casos (apesar de eu acreditar que você conseguiria fazer isso só ao salvar pelo Student com um pouco de metaprogramação)